# PHP Redirect with Custom Headers

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

I am writing a basic authorization system and I am struggling with it a bit. There are two files involved - `index.php` and `login.php`. The login form is pretty simple (it's inside `index.php`):

```
<fieldset class="right">
    <label for="email">Email

        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""/>
    </label>
    <label for="password">Password
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#password-box').toggle();" >Forgot your password?<span></span></a>
    </label>
    <div class="btn-login"><button type="submit" value="Login"></button></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The `login.php` contents:

```
<?php
//  Include the launcher file.
require_once('globals.php');
require_once(CORE . 'launcher.php');

//  Collect the information sent to us.
$mail = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

$LoginError = false;
    // AUTHORIZATION STUFF HERE
if ($LoginError) {
    header('Status: 200');
    header('X-Test: test');
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

As you can see, I'm sending a custom header to the script containing the form in case there was an error during signing in. In the `index.php`, I'm using `headers_list()`, but the header I'm sending is not present in the list.

What is causing that? I've tried with `php_value "output_buffering" "0"` in the `.htaccess` file, but no success.

**UPDATE**
After checking in Chrome, the header is being received by the browser, but is not available in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer should be clear now with four different explanations :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirect is sent to and processed by the client which responds by navigating to the given `Location: index.php`. You should not expect that the custom header is provided by the browser when it is requesting `index.php` from the server.

```
CLIENT                                    SERVER
 |------- POST login.php ------------------>|
 |                                          |
 |<- 200, Location: index.php, X-Test:test -| (this is where you send the header)
 |                                          |
 |------- GET index.php ------------------->| (no header from client to server)
```

Answer (score 3):

The headers() you specify with `header()` will be present in the output from server -> client. However, when doing a redirect, the browser will perform a **NEW** request, client -> server, and the browser is under no obligation to include your custom headers in this new request.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sending a custom header to the script containing the form

No you're not. Your sending a custom header to the client (user's browser) and the client will simply ignore/discard it.

If you need to maintain state, use a cookie/sessions or place something in the new location, e.g., `header('Location: index.php?login=false');`.

Answer (score 1):

The custom headers you are sending to the user are being received. But they're being discarded when the browser does the redirect because the browser isn't sending them to the redirected page. That's why you don't see them.