# Send a message with PHP header location redirect

Tags: php, http, header

Is it possible to include some message in a PHP header:

```
header("Location: http://somesite.com");
header("Message: hello");
```

then on site.com:

```
$message = some_function(); // "hello"
```

I am currently using a $_GET parameter in the URL, but looking for an alternative, maybe sending a $_POST?

I'm trying to not use $_GET, or use cookies (I know, those are the best ways..)

Comment: So, you want to send a header to the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: I think using `$_GET` is the best way.  Remember the `Location` header is processed by the *client*.  The browser sees it and then redirects.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10094751

Comment: Yea, something that will be available in PHP on the target page.

Comment: Why do you want an alternative to `$_GET`? Can't use sessions either because it uses cookies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to send some extra data to the page you are redirecting to.  No, this isn't possible outside of the query string.  You should understand what is happening here.

When you send a `302` or `301` status code along with a `Location:` header, the browser sees this and then makes a separate request to the URL specified by the `Location:` header.  The server isn't sending anything to that page.  It's almost as if the user simply typed in that new URL in their browser.

I say almost because in some circumstances, there is a referrer set by the browser.  This isn't guaranteed though.

What you **can** do is send some sort of token that contains more information.  Perhaps your page saves off a message in a database or something, and then you pass the ID in the query string of the URL you're redirecting to.

Also, if you set session/cookie data and you're redirecting to something on the same domain, you can read that information on the page the user eventually lands on.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that explanation helps me understand why my question will probably not have an answer!

Comment: @d-_-b Your question does have an answer... it's "no".  :-D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Brad suggested, you can also send some info using # in the url without affecting the query string and then capture it with js.

```
header("Location: http://somesite.com#success");
```

in js:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('#success')>0) {
    alert("operation successfully completed");
}
```